# MVC String in ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, actionresult

I am using the default Controller named "Home".

I have the following ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult SetID(string ID)
{
    int? result = MyGateway.GetAccountByID(ID);
    Common.IDNum = result;
    return View("Index","Home");
}
```

**I would like to pass the IDNumber like:**

```
http://localhost:3314/Home/SetID/AA3420
```

...and not like...

```
http://localhost:3314/Home/SetID?ID=AA3420
```

The link above is beginning generated by a view which returns a list. To select a record, they click "Select" which is the link above.  I am currently setting the "AA3420" to a Session Variable located in a CS file elsewhere called Common.cs.

How can I get my URL to look like: `http://localhost:3314/Home/SetID/AA3420`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Registering the following route in global.asax Application_Start:

```
 var routes = RouteTable.Routes;

 routes.MapRoute(
            "ID Action", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new {controller = "Home", action = "SetID", ID = ""} // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Comment: Thank you very much, BobTodd.  That did the trick.  I knew it had something to to with Routes, but wasn't sure how to do it correctly.  I understand now.  Much thanks your way.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your Global.asax. There you define a default route and a default parameter.
Like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```